# PostgreSQL's ARRAY type column preventing session from commit()ing via "UndefinedColumn" error

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am creating a relational database in SQLAlchemy using postgresql as the dialect and have a column defined to store postgresql.ARRAY types, among other standard columns-types. E.g.:

```
engine= create_engine('postgresql://localhost/test1',echo= False) 
base_object= declarative_base()

class AE_Class(base_object):
    __tablename__= 'AE_Table'

    date= Column(String, primary_key= True)
    experiment= Column(String)
    machine= Column(String)
    parameter1= Column(Integer)
    parameter2= Column(Integer)
    parameter3= Column(ARRAY(item_type= Integer,dimensions= 1))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<AE_Class(date= '%s',experiment= '%s',machine= '%s',parameter1= '%s',parameter2= '%s',parameter3= '%s')>"%(\
        self.date, self.experiment, self.machine, self.parameter1, self.parameter2,self.parameter3)
```

This is fine, I think. Then,

```
base_object.metadata.create_all(engine)
session_maker_obj= sessionmaker(bind= engine)
```

Then, I create a record I want to add to the databse. Here is the info I'm going to add:

```
rho_prof= {'Time': np.arange(0,20),'AirDensity': np.arange(0,20)**2}
k= '02-23-2004'
v= {'Exp':'lin vs circ polarization','Machine':'LIDAR2','Var1':32, 
'Var2':0.9,'Var3':rho_prof}}

record1= AE_Class(machine= v['Machine'],date= k, experiment= v['Exp'], 
                          parameter1= v['Var1'],parameter2= v['Var2'],
                          parameter3= v['Var3']['AirDensity'])
```

Now I open a session and add `record1` to it:

```
orm_session= session_maker_obj()
orm_session.add(record1)
```

When I inspect the session via `orm_session.new` I can see that the item is pending and waiting to be flushed:

```
>>> orm_session.new    
IdentitySet([<AE_Class(date= '02-23-2004',experiment= 'lin vs circ polarization',machine= 'LIDAR2',parameter1= '32',parameter2= '0.9',parameter3= '[  0   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100 121 144 169 196 225 256 289
     324 361]')>])
```

However, when I `orm_session.commit()`, I receive the error (truncated, since the full traceback is very long):

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "parameter3" of relation "AE_Table" does not exist
LINE 1: ...table (date, experiment, machine, parameter1, parameter3...
                                                         ^
```

How can the column be undefined? parameter3 DOES exist in the AE_Table, and I've defined it in the instance. Why does SQLAlchemy recognize it to be undefined?

Comment: The answer to "Why does SQLAlchemy recognize it to be undefined?" is it does not. It is Postgresql, and the error is self explanatory: you've created the table without the column "parameter3" and added it to your SQLA model later. You should either recreate the table or migrate it to include the new column.

Comment: @IljaEverilä To your first comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say I've created the table without the column "parameter3". It's not self-explanatory to me because I quite literally create the table in the first code snippet presented here, and this table has a column3; why wouldn't that be considered to be the creation of the table and its columns in this case?

Comment: @IljaEverilä To your second comment: I am in fact passing an array of integers, not a string -- see code snippet 3 which has been updated to show this info. It is interesting that the array is stored as a string, but I can't say that I passed it as such; this seems to be something going on under the hood with the ARRAY data type.

Comment: Ah, it was your custom `__repr__` that just displays it so. But the 1st point still stands that your database is raising the error for the missing column. Use for example `psql` to connect to your DB and inspect the table.